# Memory allocation mental map clarification

Tags: c++

I want to clarify my mental map on memory allocation.

Lets suppose I have the following Array:

```
int arr [] = {1,2,3};
```

Lets suppose each integer will occupy **4 bytes** in memory.

Such that the memory addresses of the integers could be :

*HHH01* *HHH05* *HHH09*

Will the memory chunk of `arr` be a superset of the memory chunks of each integer?

Comment: Remember to consider allignment needs of the types in your array.

Comment: I think you meant `int arr[]`.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by memory chunk. Depending on how an array is allocated there might be extra memory overhead related to how it will later be cleaned up. Whether or not you include this as part of `arr`'s "memory chunk" is a matter of interpretation. That overhead isn't part of the object as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for the clarification there, I edited my post. How about a normal array allocation?

Comment: @NicholasRawitscher An array's memory representation consists of it's element's memory representation. Because an array's state is defined entirely by it's elements, they don't need any memory for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, IIRC, the answer to your question is undefined and that's important because dipping into undefined behavior leads to some of the hardest and most obscure to track down bugs. Pointers and arrays don't necessarily have to map in memory in any specific fashion within the CPP standard. As long as they can properly perform the necessary arithmetic to find and de-reference to the proper elements, etc... anything beyond that should be considered safely abstracted away.

With that said... I think the answer to the question for most (if not all?) practical purposes is that your understanding is correct. If you were to `cout << &(arr[0]);cout << &(arr[2])` you'd get the addresses you expect in any compiler that I've used and the amount of memory allocated will be the amount you'd expect. Doing `cout << &(arr[3])` will even give you a valid address, though the data that's actually stored in `arr[3]` would be garbage. The only thing to be aware of is that different compilers and operating systems could provide different sizes and alignments of those elements. It's possible that if you were to check the size of `int` it could tell you that it's 2 bytes, but when you start looking at the addresses of the elements in an array printed out by a compiler they've got a 4-byte spacing.

In the end, while this can be interesting from an academic point of view... making actual use of it should be avoided at essentially all costs. If you start trying to manually access memory locations, it's likely to come back and bite you or whoever has to maintain your code down the line somewhere.